# jquery - remove class based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am polling a json response for every 1 min and based on the response I am adding or removing overlay on my page.
My response is most of the time positive , in this case , i should remove the overlay class.
In the below code, else part is executing every time and remove class and hide functions are executed every time.
Is there any way to avoid this . Is there any method in jquery to check whether class is added or not . Also hide is active or not.
Or can anyone give syntax to achieve this by setting and unsetting a boolean variable.

```
(function poll() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "path",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("polling" + data);
        if (data.is_running === true) {
          $("#overlay").addClass('show');
          $("#alertDiv").show();
        } else {
          console.log("removing ....");
          $("#overlay").removeClass('show');
          $("#alertDiv").hide();

        }
      },
      dataType: "json",
      complete: poll,
      timeout: 200
    })
  }, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: use hasClass method !

Answer (score 13):

You can use **[`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** and **[`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)** with `Boolean` value no need of `if...else` statement otherwise returns `false`

```
$("#overlay").toggleClass('show',data.is_running);
$("#alertDiv").toggle(data.is_running);
```

And for checking that an element has a class or not you can use **[`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)** which returns `true` if  matched elements are assigned the given class

Answer (score 4):

Try like below and keep the `$() query methods` in variable to make efficient !

```
var $overLay = $("#overlay"),
    $alertDiv = $("#alertDiv"),
    sh = 'show';

 if (data.is_running === true) {
   $overLay.addClass();
   $alertDiv.show(sh);
 } else if ($overLay.hasClass(sh)) {
   $overLay.removeClass(sh );
   $alertDiv.hide();
 }
```

Comment: How is this more efficient? Since only one of the branches of the if statement is ever executed, the DOM is only ever queried once for both elements.

Comment: What i meant efficient is about DOM :) its query only two times but its been called overlay 3 times and alertDiv 2 times

Answer (score 3):

You can check if an element has a specific class with [**`hasclass()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
var overlay = $('#overlay');

if (overlay.hasClass('show')) {
  overlay.removeClass('show');
}
```

But you can use [**`toggle()`**](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and  [**`toggleClass()`**](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), see [Pranav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101057/1374578).

Comment: Note that `if(overlay.hasClass('show')) { overlay.removeClass('show'); }` is actually _less_ efficient than calling `overlay.removeClass('show')` directly since `removeClass` also queries existence of the class first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting data.is_running as "true"

Please change your code like this

```
if (data.is_running == true){
   //your code
}
or 
if (data.is_running == "true"){
   //your code
}
```