# Remove class based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove whole div when it contains both `.section.level3` and `.tutorial-question` classes.
When I use `$('.section.level3 .tutorial-question').eq(0).remove();` it ignores tags (like h3 below) between these two classes. I want h3 to removed as well (refer html below).

I can't simply use `.section.level3` as it would remove other divs that contain only `.section.level3`. I want div to be removed based on both `.section.level3` and `.tutorial-question` [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/deepanshu88/pen/QWdJPGB) for reference

```js
$('.section.level3 .tutorial-question').eq(0).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section level3">
  <p>Testing</p>
</div>

<div class="section level3">
  <h3>Multiple Choice Questions</h3>
  <div class="tutorial-question">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q9-answer" value="8 15 12 (with some warning)">
        <span>8 15 12 (with some warning)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery - remove class based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100999/jquery-remove-class-based-on-condition)

Comment: `$('.section.level3 .tutorial-question').closest(".section").remove();` ?

Comment: What *exactly* do you want the end result to be? Your comments on answers indicate that you do not want to remove elements matched by `'.section.level3 .tutorial-question'`, but it is unclear what you do want removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery here:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".section.level3 .tutorial-question").forEach(el => el.parentElement.remove());
```

```html
<div class="section level3">
 <p>Testing</p>
</div>

<div class="section level3">
<h3>Multiple Choice Questions</h3>
<div class="tutorial-question">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q9-answer" value="8 15 12 (with some warning)">
        <span>8 15 12 (with some warning)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: "Multiple Choice Questions" should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Find it and remove the closest .section

```js
$('.section.level3 div.tutorial-question').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.section').remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section level3">
  <p>Testing</p>
</div>

<div class="section level3">
  <h3>Multiple Choice Questions</h3>
  <div class="tutorial-question">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="q9-answer" value="8 15 12 (with some warning)">
        <span>8 15 12 (with some warning)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```